# Send email as a customer using just CNAME and setting up own DKIM, SPF

Tags: email, spf, cname-record, dkim

I own mydomain.com and I am trying to send emails as mycustomer1.com, mycustomer2.com, etc. (using mailgun).

I am aware that by making my customer add DKIM and SPF records for mydomain.com will enable me to send valid emails as as them but I am trying to explore another option here.

We use intercom for support and intercom sends emails on our behalf. All intercom asked us to do is add this CNAME record:

```
NAME:  intercom._domainkey.mydomain.com
TYPE:  CNAME
VALUE: c03cd4ef-0785-43b6-a27c-eb6252f1c71c.dkim.intercom.io
```

After adding this DNS record in mydomain.com, intercom was able to send outbound emails from `support@mydomain.com` with SPF passing and DKIM passing with mydomain.com.

So I tried doing that. I added a CNAME record to mycustomer1.com:

```
NAME:  mydomain._domainkey.mycustomer1.com
TYPE:  CNAME
VALUE: foo-bar.dkim.mydomain.com
```

In mailgun, I created a domain `foo-bar.dkim.mydomain.com` and in my DNS settings for mydomain.com, I added the following records:

SPF:

```
NAME:  foo-bar.dkim.mydomain.com
TYPE:  TXT
VALUE: v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all
```

AND DKIM:

```
NAME:  mailo._domainkey.foo-bar.dkim.mydomain.com
TYPE:  TXT
VALUE: k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0...
```

This passed the SPF test. For DKIM test, it shows passed with domain mailgun.org. Mailgun signs the message from domain `foo-bar.dkim.mydomain.com`.

What I want is the message to be signed from domain `mycustomer1.com` as intercom does. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you contacted intercom / mailgun and / or have you gone through their documentation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this requires knowledge of specific vendors (intercom and mailgun) that are likely off-topic as in the case of questions involving web hosting control panels.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu Yes, I have tried contacting mailgun and I have spend a few hours going through documentation and other forums.

Comment: Also, I do not believe this is off-topic. This is less related to mailgun/intercom and more about the setup of DNS records to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The CNAME `intercom._domainkey.mydomain.com` is setup so Intercom can rotate the signing key without requiring you to update the DNS record every time it need to be rotated.  It is also the dkim selector thats embedded within the email so the receiving server can use the right key to verify.

When you created a CNAME on `mydomain._domainkey.mycustomer1.com`, the email also would need to reflect this in the header, but it will not as the emails sent will have `mailo._domainkey.foo-bar.dkim.mydomain.com` as the signing key.

You will need to add the customers domain to Mailgun instead. https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#verifying-your-domain

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I tried adding `mail.mycustomer1.com` as a domain in mailgun but I couldn't get it to verify the SPF and DKIM records. I believe I am missing the link between `mail.mycustomer1.com` and `foo-bar.dkim.mydomain.com`.

Comment: What records are you adding for `mail.mycustomer1.com`? It should be a txt record on `mail.mucustomer1.com` and a txt on `smtp._domainkey.mail.mycustomer1.com`